# Openlayer V4:How to make GracticluevGrid or tileGrid Selectable on single click

Tags: openlayers

I have Openlayer Canvas TIle source as tileDebug and Gracticlue Grid using the setMap method to display Grid in Client Side.Namely created two BaseLayer CanvasTile and GracticlueGrid.

I am able to get zoom level, grid,coord, extent etc. but not getting the selectable grid on single-click.I'm also adding select interaction on the map but it's not working.

I am following the Openlayer example link
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/canvas-tiles.html
 and https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/graticule.html

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Select Features</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
     var tileGrid = new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.TileDebug({
                  tileGrid: new ol.source.OSM().getTileGrid({
                    tileSize:[512, 512]
                  }),
                  projection:'EPSG:4326'
                })
        });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [tileGrid],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });

      map.on('singleclick',function(event){
      var z = map.getView().getZoom();
      var coordinate = event.coordinate;
      var grid = tileGrid.getSource().getTileGrid();

      var coord = grid.getTileCoordForCoordAndZ(coordinate,z);
      var extend = grid.getTileCoordExtent(coord);


      // **select interaction not working on "singleclick"**
      var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select();
      map.addInteraction(selectSingleClick);

      });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Excepted Output on single click:
[image]

Please, any help to get same?

Comment: what is it you want to get, the numbers of the tile?

Comment: No. On click, I want to highlight or select the tile.for example in above image tile 2,1,-2. on click, it should be a highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select graticule grids or tiledebug, because they are only paint (done with postcompose) and not real map elements. However, you already figured out how to get the tile extent, so just use it and draw a LineString (or Polygon) on an extra layer (`highlightVector` in the example below).

```js
const osmTile = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM(),
  opacity: 0.5
});

const grid = new ol.source.OSM().getTileGrid({
  tileSize:[512, 512]
});

var grildTile = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileDebug({
    tileGrid: grid,
    projection:'EPSG:4326'
  })
});

const highlightVector = new ol.source.Vector();
const highlightLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: highlightVector,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 3,
      color: [255, 0, 0, 1]
    })
  })
});

const view = new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [osmTile, grildTile, highlightLayer],
  target: 'map',
  view: view,
});


view.on('change:resolution', function(event){
  // zooming changes tile sizes
  highlightVector.clear();
});

map.on('singleclick',function(event){
  var z = map.getView().getZoom();
  var coord = grid.getTileCoordForCoordAndZ(event.coordinate, z);
  var extent = grid.getTileCoordExtent(coord);

  highlightVector.clear();
  highlightVector.addFeature(new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.LineString([
      [ extent[0],extent[1] ],
      [ extent[0],extent[3] ],
      [ extent[2],extent[3] ],
      [ extent[2],extent[1] ],
      [ extent[0],extent[1] ],
    ])
  }));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Dube.I have one more question there is any other way to make the grid from shapefile for Western Canada? Like in this site implemented https://www.petroninja.com/  at zoom level getting grid with marker label with township etc.

Comment: Maybe use [shp2geojeson](https://github.com/gipong/shp2geojson.js), it can convert shapefiles in geojson, which you then can use with OpenLayers

Comment: Thanks for the reply.No Dube, I want Grid shape files related to Western Canada.

Comment: @cp8 the service I mentioned is a converte for shapefile to geojson, it's not a dataprovider. But create an other question, if you need to know more

Comment: Ok, Thanks.Yeah, I created another question in Open data StackExchange https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12647/western-canada-shape-filesmeridian-township-section-and-quarter-to-create-gr.